# How do I concat numpy columns?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with the dimensions 216 x 3. Is there a pythonic way to concat these "columns" together? As these are not really columns, I don't know how to approach this problem. Many thanks!

A sample of my data:

```
print(Allcombos)
    SSU MSU LSU
    SSU MSU LU
    SSU MSU LWU
    SSU MSU LWD
    SSU MSU LD
```

My desired output:

```
SSUMSULSU
SSUMSULU
SSUMSULWU
SSUMSULWD
SSUMSULD
```

Comment: Just use `arr.sum(1)`, but why are you storing data like this in the first place, and why does it need to be concated?

Comment: Because I've calculated all combinations of a list of lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr=np.array([['SSU' ,'MSU','LSU'],
              ['SSU', 'MSU', 'LU'],
              ['SSU', 'MSU', 'LWU']]
            )
arr1=[]
for i in arr:
    arr1.append("".join(i))
```

output

```
['SSUMSULSU', 'SSUMSULU', 'SSUMSULWU']
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for and too tired to figure out by myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Convert the NumPy array to pandas data frame and perform column concatenation.  You can convert back to NumPy array if you want.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(np_array, columns=['column1', 'column2']
df['new_column']=df['column1']+df['column2']

#if you want numpy array

np_values=df['new_column'].values
```

Comment: That's the best solution. Thanks Ravi!

Comment: Thanks, @Vichtor. If you like the answer please accept the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.column_stack` like so:

```py
import numpy as np

array = np.ones([216,3], dtype=str)
result = np.column_stack((array[:,0],array[:,1],array[:,2]))
print(result)
```

Out:

```
[['1' '1' '1']
 ['1' '1' '1']
 ['1' '1' '1']
 ['1' '1' '1']
 ['1' '1' '1']
 ['1' '1' '1']
...
```

This example uses an array full of ones for simplicity, but the same approach would work identically in your use case.